# Get index position for a JSON item in Python

Tags: python, json

I need to be able to get the index position of a certain item within a JSON file using Python so that I am able to append something to another item within that same position.

JSON below:

```
{
    "members": [{
            "username": "John Doe#0001",
            "possesions": []
        },
        {
            "username": "Samantha Green#0001",
            "possesions": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to find what position in `members` John Doe#0001 is in for example. So I can then append something to the `possesions` list like so:

```
data = json.load(jsonFile)
temp = data['members'][Index position]['possesions']
temp.append("something")
```

Ive tried googling to no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all the members until you find the one you want:

```
data = json.load(jsonFile)
for member in data['members']:
    if member['username'] == 'John Doe#0001':
        member['posessions'].append(something)
```

Comment: This solution skips the index number altogether, which is usually simpler; however, if the index number is needed for some purpose, the [`enumerate` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) can provide it: `for i, member in enumerate(data['members']): ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
    
json_file={
    "members": [{
            "username": "John Doe#0001",
            "possesions": []
        },
        {
            "username": "Samantha Green#0001",
            "possesions": []
        }
    ]
}

dicti = json.loads(json_file)

for i in range(len(dicti)):
    if dict['members'][i]['username'] == "John Doe#0001":
        print(i)
```

But before that, you must check if your data is in JSON format. If it is in the dictionary then it will show an error in this

`dicti = json.loads(json_file)` line.

Comment: You want `range(len(dict['members']))`, not `range(len(dict))`.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is a dictionary in Python. It is not indexed but can be looped through using keys.
If you want to replace the value of the particular key, you can replace directly using

`data["key"]=new_value`